# Create an AJAX Overlay with text

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I am wanting to use AJAX to create a screen area that overlays on the current window.  An example of one of these is like those adverts that don't open in a new window or when you are on reddit and try and vote on a post without being logged in.  I can't find any documentation on such a thing.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very much clear what you are asking.But What I undestood is , you want an overlay when ajax request is sent. 
So, the solution for that is below .
In Html :

With Jquery :

```
$.ajax({                
        url: "@Url.Action("GetMyCandidate")",           
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",// your type
        beforeSend: function () {              

            // show your overlay div
            $("#overlay").show();

         }
    }).success(function (data) {
         $("#overlay").hide();
          // your futher code

     });
```